# Regex Only Match After 2nd Forward Slash

Tags: regex

3 string examples:

`/string-to-match/1234/`

`/dont/1234/match/`

`/dont/match/1234/`

I only want to match the first example. My curent regex matches 1 and 3:

`(\/[0-9]{4}\/$)`

I assume there is a way to make it only match after 2 occurances of a forward slash, but I've tried hundreds of search terms and cannot find an example.

Link: https://regex101.com/r/RX6Em8/1

*Alternatively*, doing something like this in MySQL would be sufficient, but I cannot get that working either
`LIKE '/%/[0-9]{4}/'`

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to capture the number only if it's preceded by two forward slashes and it's at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, you are not specifying where do you gonna place the regex (Python, Java, C#, etc.)

In a general way, you could try this:

Using the `start (^)` and `end ($)` string syntax I place this regex, matching the first case.

`^/[^/]+/\d{4}/$`

[Regex101- Example](https://regex101.com/r/usV5gm/1)